# Magento 2.4.5 customer-data.js not initiating in Custom theme js file

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5, requirejs-config.js, magento2.4.5p1

I have a function of ajax add to cart in below file and doing section reload.
below code is in app/design/frontend/MyThemeNS/Mytheme/web/js/custom.js (just mentioning sample for understanding.)

```
require([
  'jquery',
  'mage/url',
  'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
], function ($, url, customerData) {
....
    ajax call function {
     on success : {
       .....
      var sections = ['cart'];
      customerData.reload(sections, true);
    }
  }
......
}
```

File : Magento_Customer/js/customer-data is not initiating.
upon more debugging i found in chain of js libirary dependency initialising the last file lib/web/js-storage/storage-wrapper.js is containing 'js-storage/js.storage' file which is not initialising.

i checked the magento2 release 2.4.5 and saw this.

```
julien-maurel/js-storage instead of jQuery Strograe libraries
```

is this magento bug or any other way i can do section reload after ajax add to cart in my custom theme custom function.

i am stuck and not able to find solution. can someone support if known any such issue.

Comment: try to add customerData.invalidate(sections); on above customerData.reload(sections, true);

Comment: on page load, 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data' itself not initializing, due to that.my custom js itself not working. if i remove 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data' then my custom js works, but unable to reload sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a issue 2.4.5 with cookies and storage dependency.
here is the patch need to apply.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35913
this solves my problem.